# Warning C4047 and C4024 when trying to append characters to string

Tags: c, string, char, strcat

I got a code that wants to place all the latters in the English alphabet into a string, The problem is, is that Visual Studio gives me this: Warning

```
warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'
```

and this: Warning 2

```
warning C4024: 'strcat' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
```

Here is the code, please tell me what is wrong with it that it can't be compiled correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 27
void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main()
{
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";
    makeABC(abcString);
    puts(abcString);
    return (0);
}

void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    char letter;
    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        strcat(abc, letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think `char` and `char *` are of different type?

Comment: `strcat()` expects two `char`-pointers, not a `char`-pointer and a `char`.

Comment: The ASCII alphabet has 25 letters only.

Comment: @alk Actually it has 26, and the 27th is for the null character.

Comment: @zenith: Hu, you are correct. Btw, I am aware of the `0`-terminator, but I simply counted wrongly ... :-}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard C function `strcat` deals with character strings. Thus if you want certanly to use function `strcat` then the loop can look like

```
void makeABC( char abc[NUM_ABC_LET] )
{
    char letter[] = "a";
    for ( ; letter[0] <= 'z'; letter[0]++ )
    {
        strcat( abc, letter );
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome you helped me a lot thanks. But can you explain to me what was the compilation error and what was the run time error?

Comment: @Amnon Hanuhov  In fact this warning "warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'" means  that the function requires a pointer to character (that is an indirect access to an object by means of its pointer) as the second parameter but you are using a scalar character not a pointer. The same meaning has the second warning.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 strcat(abc, letter);
```

to

```
  abc[letter - 'a'] = letter;
```

Then add

```
abc[26]  = 0;
```

Comment: This is not very helpful because it doesn't explain *why* the solution works, and why the OP's code doesn't.

Comment: @zenith: Correct ... - **but** it is the most efficient solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` takes two `char` *pointers* that point to C-strings i.e. null terminated char arrays.

You're passing it `letter` which is a `char`, not a C-string. Try again.

Answer (score -4):

You have to pass as 2arg of strcat a char * arg, so you have to change

```
strcat(abc, letter)
```

to

```
strcat(abc, &letter)
```

This will eliminate the segfault of your previous code.

Comment: This won't work since both parameters must be *null-terminated* strings. `&letter` is just a pointer to char, without the null terminator.

Comment: `strcat` expects both its arguments to be NUL-terminated. Your suggestion thus invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Drome We just told you. This answer is not useful because it doesn't solve the OP's problem.